# CSS rule in external file does not affect section

Tags: html, css

In an external CSS file I have:

```
section.venues
{
    display: none;
}
```

And I include the file like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
```

Other CSS rules are picked up and affect the page but my section is not affected. I have to have the CSS rule in the actual page where the section is.

My section:

```
<section class="venues">...</section>
```

Comment: Are there other styles being applied to the section elements? Anything that could overrule yours?

Comment: Examine the section element in your browser's DOM inspector. It will tell you which CSS rules are being applied and in what order.

Comment: FIrst, ensure the CSS file is being imported into the document.  Then make sure the selector us accurate and applies to the element that you intend.  Then make sure your rule isn't overriden by a more specific rule.  Browser dev tools like Firebug or built-in dev consoles can answer all these questions.

Comment: It was an inheritance issue